# HTML (table) to Libre office

Tags: discussion

I have the following question:

> I have a large table (also containing multiple tables and images), written in Seamonkey (my preferred HTML editor).  I want to transfer it to either a .doc or a pdf without too much hassle.  Firstly putting it into libreoffice write it doesn't copy the complete table, it misses out parts.  So, tried putting it into abiword - but that editor keeps on refusing to save the images, (looks great whilst editing, go to save it, re-open and hey presto all images have gone!).  Can anyone help?

Would this be on topic on the main site?

Comment: This should be posted on the main site, you're on meta.

Comment: Yup, I just thought that I would ask it here first to see if I was in the right area of stackexchange to ask this question.  Many thanks.

Comment: a loooong time ago i used [Table2Clipboard](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/dafizilla-table2clipboard/)... maybe worth a look.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you could ask on the main site. However, please make sure to

1. Include an example file we can play with to test our answers.
2. Explain *how* you "put it" into AbiWord or libreoffice. Did you copy paste? From what program? Did you open it from the target program?